# Why username is logging undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Why username is logging undefined? i have a user object which is coming from another screen by navigation and route but i want to call the username from that user object so I tried to do console.log(user.username) but then it logs undefined and when I only log user then it gives whole user result as expected but then why is it giving username undefined?

```
const { user } = route.params;
console.log(user.username)
console.log(user)
```

User Log Result:

```
 LOG  [{"_id": "63c42922dc60a84421e8f843", "photos": [[Object]], "profileImg": "Image uri here",  "username": "Test"}]
```

Comment: "*User Log Result:*" it shows an array which has one item in it. So, take the one item, instead of trying to get the username property of the array. Arrays do not have a username property.

Answer (score 4):

Examine the log closely. The result is an array, not an object.

To be able to access the username, you need to access the first element of the array.

```
console.log(user[0].username)
```

I suggest you try to figure out why `params.user` is an array and not an object.